# Probability set theory: $\Omega \backslash (A \cap B) = (\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

My probability theory book (Grimmett & Welsh) contains the following formula:

> $\Omega \backslash (A \cap B) = (\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega$
>   $\backslash B)$

But drawing Venn diagrams, this equality does not seem to hold up?

$\Omega \backslash (A \cap B)$ gives me a Venn diagram where only $(A \cap B)$ is missing, so $A \backslash B$ and $B \backslash A$ are not missing. 
$(\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)$ gives me a Venn diagram where both $A$ and $B$ are completely missing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I draw the Venn diagram, it does seem to hold up.

Comment: $\Omega \backslash (A \cap B)$ gives me a Venn diagram where only $(A \cap B)$ is missing, so $A \backslash B$ and $B \backslash A$ are not missing. 
$(\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)$ gives me a Venn diagram where both $A$ and $B$ are completely missing.

Comment: I think it is crucial to show the Ven diagram you have for the second expression so we can tell precisely what's wrong. It seems like that's where the problem is.

Comment: You can use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=A+set+minus+(B+intersect+C)) to visualize Venn diagrams of sets.  For instance, type "A set minus (B intersect C)" to see $A \setminus (B \cap C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Venn diagram below, let $A$ ($B$) denote the content of the circle on the left (right), so $A\cap B$ is the yellow part and $\Omega\backslash (A\cap B)$ is the union of the red, blue and white parts (the white part being outside both circles). Meanwhile, $\Omega\backslash A$ is anything that's blue or white, $\Omega\backslash B$ is anything that's red or white, and $(\Omega\backslash A)\cup(\Omega\backslash B)$ is anything that's red, blue or white, as expected. I suggest you look over your own Venn diagram again to see which of these facts you misunderstood. I suspect you accidentally considered $(\Omega\backslash A)\cap(\Omega\backslash B)$, which is just the white part.

[image: Coloured Venn diagram]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would also appreciate a proof that uses the logical definition of the meaning of equality $\Omega \backslash (A \cap B) = (\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)$ without appealing to a drawing.
Note that each of the following statements are equivalent:

1. $\Omega \backslash (A \cap B) = (\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)$
2. $\Omega \backslash (A \cap B) \subseteq (\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)$ and  $(\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)\subseteq \Omega \backslash (A \cap B)$
3. $x\in \Omega \backslash (A \cap B) $ implies $x\in (\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)$ and  $x\in (\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)  $ implies $x\in \Omega \backslash (A \cap B) $

First we will prove the implication: $x\in \Omega \backslash (A \cap B) $ implies $x\in (\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)$. Note that each of the statements below results in the next statement.

- $x\in \Omega \backslash (A \cap B) $,
- $x\in \Omega$ and  $x\notin(A \cap B) $,
- $x\in \Omega$ and  $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B $,
- $x\in \Omega$ and  $x\notin A$ and  $x\in \Omega$  and $x\notin B $
- $x\in \Omega\backslash A$ and $x\in \Omega\backslash B$
- $x\in (\Omega\backslash A)\cap (\Omega\backslash B)$

Now we will prove the implication $x\in (\Omega \backslash A) \cup (\Omega \backslash B)  $ implies $x\in \Omega \backslash (A \cap B) $. Notice again that each of the statements below results in the next statement.

- $x\in (\Omega\backslash A)\cap (\Omega\backslash B)$,
- $x\in \Omega\backslash A$ and $x\in \Omega\backslash B$,
- $x\in \Omega$ and  $x\notin A$ and  $x\in \Omega$  and $x\notin B $
- $x\in \Omega$ and  $x\notin A$ and $x\notin B $,
- $x\in \Omega$ and  $x\notin(A \cap B) $,